# Add non-datetime variables in SQL python as function parameters

Tags: python, sql, function, variables

I have a function that executes many SQL queries with different dates.

What I want is to pass all dates and other query variables as function parameters and then just execute the function. I have figured out how to do this for datetime variables as below. But I also have a query that looks at specific `campaign_names` in a database and pulls those as strings. I want to be able to pass those strings as function parameters but I haven't figured out the correct syntax for this in the SQL query.

```
def Camp_eval(start_date,end_1M,camp1,camp2,camp3):
    
    query1 = f"""SELECT CONTACT_NUMBER, OUTCOME_DATE
            FROM DATABASE1
            where OUTCOME_DATE >= (to_date('{start_date}', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) 
            and OUTCOME_DATE < (to_date('{end_1M}', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))"""

    query2 = """SELECT CONTACT_NUMBER
            FROM DATABASE2
            WHERE (CAMP_NAME = {camp1} or
            CAMP_NAME = {camp2} or
            CAMP_NAME = {camp3})"""

Camp_eval('01/04/2022','01/05/2022','Camp_2022_04','Camp_2022_05','Camp_2022_06')
```

The parameters `start_date` and `end_1M` work fine with the `{}` brackets but the `camp` variables, which are strings don't return any results even though there are results in the database with those conditions if I were to write them directly in the query.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: You need an `f` before `"""SELECT CONTACT_NUMBER` to make it an f-string so that the variables will be inserted into the string. By the way, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: @DMalan of course - I missed that `f string`! How do i fix the SQL interjection problem??

Comment: https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/

Answer (score -2):

Please, do not use f-strings for creating SQL queries!
Most likely, any library you use for accessing a database already has a way of creating queries: [SQLite docs (check code examples)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=execute#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).
Another example: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE priority = ?", (priority,))`.

Not only this way is safer (fixes SQL Injection problem mentioned by @d-malan in comments), but it also eliminates the need to care about how data is represented in SQL - the library will automatically cast dates, strings, etc. in what they need to be casted into. Therefore, your problem can be fixed by using **proper** instruments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).